# Format value from ng-model

Tags: angularjs

When I output a variable like this I can format it to decimal places:

`{{variable|number:2}}`

How would I do the same thing in a text input?

`<input type="text" ng-model="variable">`

This doesn't work:

`<input type="text" ng-model="variable|number:2">`

Answer (score 1):

Filter are not allowed to use on ng-model.

Create directive and watch model value and update it upon change.

Answer (score 0):

//You can add watch in controller as well. Here is the sample

```
$scope.$watch('variable', function() {
        $scope.variable= "Here add your logic";
  });
```

Comment: FYI: Explore this url to use filters within controller/service etc....                                      https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter